# sqlite database connection in c# to make a windows store app

Tags: windows-store-apps

I want to make a form and store its data in sqlite database for windows store app in windows 8.I am using visual studio 2012.I have made the form in xaml. The fields are like name,age etc.
I am a beginner so I want to know how and where to write the code to do this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Robert Green's video and blog post about using SQLite in Windows Store Apps

[Channel 9 video - Using SQLite in Windows Store Apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Using-SQLite-in-Windows-Store-Apps)

[Blog post - Using SQLite in Windows 8 Store Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx)

Comment: Great tutorial.Helped me a lot.other tutorials are also good for developing for windows phone and windows store.